# Is there a way to show on the backend dashboard order page that a coupon was used? in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to show on the backend dashboard order page that a coupon was used? in wordpress. I want to display the which coupon is used by which user in backend. In order management tab.

https://prnt.sc/QQ5nTvfy-aYm - Here i want to display coupon code.

I am try it with searching but not found the exact result.